# Configuring gulpfile.js for PHP server and Browser Sync

Tags: php, server, gulp, localhost, browser-sync

I would like to locally create a PHP server that watches changes on my files with Browser Sync. I would like it to open new tab in my browser and display content of index.php file. My gulpfile.js :

```
var gulp = require('gulp'); 
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(); //reloading while saving file
var php = require('gulp-connect-php'); //for PHP server

// ------------------------------------------------- //
// --------- Server and watching for changes --------//
// ------------------------------------------------- //


gulp.task('php', function() {
    php.server({ base: 'src', port: 8080, keepalive: true, hostname: 'localhost'});
});

gulp.task('browser-sync',['php'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 8080
    });
});

gulp.task('htmlServer', function() {
   gulp.src(['src/*.+(html|ico|php)'])
   .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
   }));;
});

gulp.task('stylesServer', function() {
   gulp.src(['src/styles/*.css'])
   .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
   }));
});

gulp.task('jsServer', function() {
    gulp.src(['src/scripts/*.js'])
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
   }));
});

// --------- wrapped together --------- //

gulp.task('server', ['browser-sync','php','htmlServer','stylesServer','jsServer'], function() {
    gulp.watch('src/styles/*.css',['stylesServer']);
    gulp.watch('src/*.+(html|php)',['htmlServer']);
    gulp.watch('src/scripts/*.js',['jsServer']);
});
```

But when I start gulp server task it pops out new tab in browser and keeps loading like on the screen:

[image]

Can someone help me? I was looking in many tutorials but nothing worked and I don't want to get more and more confused. Thank You in advance for Your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var gulp = require('gulp'); 
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(); //reloading while saving file
var php = require('gulp-connect-php'); //for PHP server
```

check this section you write gulp but you have required to write gulp.php and where you calling any file name you must add extension of file then you call this file in your project